# how to get instances from a class that inherits from another class with datatableBundle and symfony

Tags: symfony, datatables

I have an employee and a user class that inherits from the employee.
I want to display only the instances of the employed class. I use ***stwe\datatableBundle*** and *symfony version 3.4*.

I tried that code but it didn't work.

```
$responseService = $this->get('sg_datatables.response');
        $responseService->setDatatable($datatable);
        $datatableQueryBuilder = $responseService->getDatatableQueryBuilder();
        /** @var QueryBuilder $qb */
        $qb = $datatableQueryBuilder->getQb();
        $qb->andWhere('e INSTANCE OF :employee');
        $qb->setParameter('employee', $em->getClassMetadata('App\Entity\Employee'));

        return $responseService->getResponse();
```

Comment: when I write this line it just shows me all instances of both classes not the employee one it also shows me the user class
$qb->andWhere('employee INSTANCE OF AppBundle\Entity\Employee');

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution you have to change the querybuilder request to

```
 $qb->where('employee NOT INSTANCE OF AppBundle\Entity\User');
```

instead

```
$qb->where('employee INSTANCE OF AppBundle\Entity\Employee');
```